# Jscrollpane in a fancybox doesn't work

Tags: jquery, fancybox, jscrollpane

I have a problem using the jscrollpane in a fancybox.
Although after a nightmare of efforts I made the custom scrollbar to appear, it only appears the first time I open the lightbox. When I close the lightbox, and try to open it again, it looks like the jscrollpane finds no content and consequently doesn't run properly.

Having a constant look at the firebug, I notice that when I close the lightbox, only the jspScrollable class (added by the jscrollpane) remains but all of the extra html is gone. When I open it again, the extra html is not created any more. It looks that this time the jscrollpane runs before the content is loaded.

Here is my script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" >

    $(document).ready(function() {

            $("a.enlarge-image").fancybox(
                 {
                   'overlayColor' : '#000',
                   'overlayOpacity' : '0.6',
                   'autoScale' : false,
                   'onComplete' : (function(){
                         $('#fancybox-content').jScrollPane();

            })
        })
    })

     </script>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: delete "(" in  'onComplete' : (function

Comment: Thanks for that,
Didn't work though. The result was exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

I finally worked this out. I firstly created an jscrollpane object which I destroy everytime I close the fancybox (onClosed) and recreate it again every time I open the fancybox (onComplete).

So here is my script now:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var scrollpane;
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $("a.enlarge-image").fancybox(
                                        {       
                'overlayColor' : '#000',
                'overlayOpacity' : '0.6',
                'autoScale' : false,
                'onComplete' : (function(){
                    scrollpane = $('#fancybox-content').jScrollPane({showArrows: true, scrollbarWidth : '20'}).data().jsp;
                       }),
                'onStart' : (function(){
                        }),
                'onClosed' : (function() {

                     scrollpane.destroy();
                       })

                    });
                })
                    </script>
```

This seems to make the fancybox and the jscrollpane inside working perfect together.
However, I discovered a problem just on IE7 & IE6 browsers. So when I close the overlay window I get this error: *'0.nodeName' is null or not an Object*

I think that the problem is that when I destroy the scrollpane onClose, then there is no declared variable *scrollpane*. I just don't know how to fix that.

Any thoughts please? Cheers..

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and spent about 10 hours to make the scrollpane works in the fancybox.
So. You should use an old fancy **1.3.4**, and use a jscrollpane *Version: **2.0.0beta12**, Last updated: 2012-09-27* from github from demo.

JS code:

```
$.fancybox(img, {
                    'padding': 0,
                    'width': 1000,
                    'centerOnScroll': false,
                    'overlayOpacity' : 0,
                    'autoScale' : false,
                    'onComplete' : (function(){
                        if (scrollpane) scrollpane.reinitialise();
                        else 
                        scrollpane = $('.fancybox-content').jScrollPane({showArrows: false,
                        verticalGutter: 30}).data().jsp;                    
                           })
                });
```

And only one thing to make it work fine after closing and next button clicking is add to the jquery.jscrollpane.js 89'th line.

```
pane = undefined;
```